# How do I dependency inject in Laravel when already using constructor params?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

This is a question aimed at Laravel for PHP.

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected $value1;
    protected $value2;
    protected $value3;

    public function __construct($value1, $value2, $value3) 
    {
        $this->value1 = $value1;
        $this->value2 = $value2;
        $this->value3 = $value3;
    }
}

class ClassToBeInjected
{
    public function doSomething() {}
}

class ClassOne extends AbstractClass
{
    public function __construct($value1, $value2, $value3) 
    {
        parent::__construct($value1, $value2, $value3);
    }
}

class ClassTwo extends AbstractClass
{
    public function __construct($value1, $value2, $value3) 
    {
        parent::__construct($value1, $value2, $value3);
    }
}
```

Hi. Have a look at the example above. I have two classes, ClassOne and ClassTwo, that both extend AbstractClass. I want both of these classes to be able to use `doSomething()` from `ClassToBeInjected`

Now my real question is, how do I inject the class when I am already using the constructor? Imagine I have a service that calls ClassOne or ClassTwo like so: `new ClassOne(1, 2, 3);`

I can't just add ´ClassToBeInjected´ to the signatures because that would mess up my typehinting, making it look like it needs to be manually passed in. A coworker suggested to use a trait on the abstract class, but that seems a bit weird to me. Someone on Laravel IRC suggested that I do it like this:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected $value1;
    protected $value2;
    protected $value3;
    protected $injectedClass;

    public function __construct($value1, $value2, $value3)
    {
        $this->value1        = $value1;
        $this->value2        = $value2;
        $this->value3        = $value3;
        $this->injectedClass = app()->make(ClassToBeInjected::class);
    }
}
```

This example works and I can live with it. But I am not sure if its the correct approach and if it could cause any problems later, doing it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the injected parameters before your constructor parameters:

```
class ClassWithInjections {
    public function __construct(FirstClassToBeInjected $class1, SecondClassToBeInjected $class2, $parameter1, $parameter2) {

    }
}
```

Then to use your class you must make it within app container:

```
$instance = app()->make(ClassWithInjections::class, ['parameter1value', 'parameter2value'])
```

This feature is not well documented, but there's a example on [Controllers Dependency Injection Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) that says:

> You may still type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` and access your
>   id parameter by defining your controller method as follows:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Update the given user.
>  *
>  * @param  Request  $request
>  * @param  string  $id
>  * @return Response
>  */
> public function update(Request $request, $id)
> {
>     //
> }
> ```

So since the controller method is also resolved by the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container), I've assumed that the same will work for any injections. Reading the [`app()->make()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Contracts/Container/Container.html#method_make) method you'll find that's true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's documented. I'll search!

Comment: @SeverinDK I've improved the answer.

Comment: As no other answers have come in and your answer is valid, I will make this the accepted answer. Thank you for the help.